# Pegar ID imediatamente após uma inserção

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq

Uso Entity e LINQ. Gostaria de saber como eu faço para obter um ID gerado logo após inserir um registro, antes que qualquer outra pessoa possa inserir também, ou seja, garantir que aquele ID é o gerado por mim. Tem como? Uso Sql Server 2008, Entity, LINQ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O Entity Framework faz isso sozinho pra você. Segue um exemplo:

```cs
var registroDaMinhaEntidade = new Entidade { Propriedade = "Uma propriedade qualquer, sei lá" };
context.Entidades.Add(registroDaMinhaEntidade);
context.SaveChanges();

// Depois do SaveChanges, se sua coluna for Identity, você deve ter o Id assim:
var idDaEntidade = registroDaMinhaEntidade.Id;
```

Comment: Cigano entendi, mas uma outra pessoa poderia ter dados um insert também e eu pegar o ID gerado por último e não o que eu gerei. No sql server tem uma função que faz isso, ou seja, garante que o ID gerado é aquele e pronto. Só não sei qual

Comment: Então, mas esqueça isso no Entity Framework. Ele já pega o `scope_identity` automaticamente.

Comment: @pnet, o entity framework já pega exatamente o ID gerado e coloca no atributo ID do seu Model, como disse o Cigano.

Answer (score 3):

Basta fazer como o código abaixo

```
Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa();
pessoa.nome = "Paulo";
context.AddObject(pessoa);
context.SaveChanges();
int id = pessoa.Id;
```

Depois que você chama SaveChanges(); o Entity já carrega p/ você o Id.

Answer (score 2):

**No Entity**

```
context.SaveChanges();
int id = ClasseContexto.Id;
```

**No SQL**

```
SELECT @@IDENTITY
```

Você poderia executar a seguinte instrução no MS SQL(tSQL)

```
INSERT tabela_Exemplo (coluna1) values (@valor1)  IF (@@ERROR = 0) SELECT @@IDENTITY AS RETORNO
```

ele retornaria um campo 'retorno' com o valor da ID

Desde que seja um campo com chave extrangeira